# Подскажите бесплатные библиотеки c# для использования SOCKS4/5

Tags: c#, dll, proxy

Собственно вопрос задан, могу добавить только, что с xNet у меня неизвестные проблемы, поэтому ее не предлагать. Нашел еще VikingEngine, но не могу понять как ею пользоваться, хелп у меня не открылся почему-то.

Да и думаю, полезно было бы собрать тут несколько библиотек, для тех, кто будет искать.

Comment: curl прекрасно работает с проксями. Говорят, даже в c# можно подключить.

Comment: Про curl знаю, постоянно им пользуюсь, очень заинтересовала возможность подключить. Можно подробнее?

Comment: Гуглил и прочитал про возможность. Я C# не использую.

Comment: Через Берлин на Марьино. Вы не туда смотрите. Curl - для PHP, для C# есть гораздо больше возможностей. Мало того - вы сами можете реализовать подключение через Socks 4\5 прокси, RFC в открытом доступе. Но как я и говорил в прошлой вашей теме - ищите проблему у себя, неизвестно как поведет себя другая библиотека (возможно так же не будет работать).

Comment: Сам не могу, к сожалению, пока опыта не хватает и мне на это понадобится довольно много времени. А по поводу поиска у себя проблемы - на днях буду переходить на win 8, может это поможет. Потому что где именно искать, я понятия не имею. В любом случае, полезно было бы знать об аналогах.

Кстати cURL мне для моих нужд пока хватает. В общем, переставлю систему, посмотрю, как поведет себя библиотека.

Comment: а чем конкретно проблемы с xNet у меня все отлично с соксами работает?

Comment: Уже все нормально, почему-то не работал на Win 7 x64 у меня. Перешел на 8, все заработало.